# Can I send email in Yahoo Pipes?

Tags: email, yahoo-pipes

Can I and if so then how?

Comment: Voted to close as not programming related

Comment: Yahoo Pipes is all about programming. Check out all other questions tagged `yahoo-pipes`...

Comment: The Web Service Module is your best bet. If you need to implement it with WCF, I wrote a blog article on how it can be done at http://bit.ly/aP5GD8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't with the built-in modules. Your only chance is using the [Web Service Module](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=operators#WebService) to feed the data to an external service that sends the mail.

Answer (score 1):

Since Yahoo Pipes ends up serving your data through RSS you can use an RSS to email gateway such as [RSSFWD](http://www.rssfwd.com/) or [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) to send emails from one of your pipes.